# SQL: group by without using aggregate function

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have the following SQL query:

```
select * from my_table
```

then the returned results looks like:

```
my_id    field_1    field_2   ...
 1         ...       ...
 1         ...       ... 
 1         ...       ...
 2
 3
 3
```

I only want to keep one record per `my_id`, perhaps taking the record with minimum value in `field_2`

Therefore, I am expecting the following query to fail becauseI haven't put a desired aggregation function after `select`:

```
select * from my_table group by my_id order by my_id
```

However, the query went through and returned table have no duplicated `my_id`. Therefore, I am wondering is there a default method SQL is using if I didn't specify an aggregation function before `group by`?

Answer (score 2):

> I am expecting the following query to fail because I haven't put a
>   desired aggregation ..

Unfortunately, some SQL Implementations allow GROUP BY *without* an aggregate function<sup>1</sup>.

In this case the result is "not defined / implementation defined" - see the specific implementation documentation to see if it provides any guarantees. That is, while it is still guaranteed that the `my_id` column is unique, ***values from any row*** could be returned for other output fields.

(Obviously, if `my_id` were a key / candidate key - but it is not in this case - then this doesn't make a difference as only one row *could* be selected..)

For increased compatibility and predictable results, ***use an aggregate function*** for every field which is not covered by the GROUP BY - *even if* the particular SQL/RDBMS does not enforce or "require" the use aggregates.

---

<sup>1</sup> While the original query is "accepted" in MySQL ([depending on ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)), both PostgreSQL and SQL Server would have *rejected* the original query "as expected".

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from my_table t
where t.field2 = (select min(t2.field2)
                  from my_table t2
                  where t2.my_id = t.my_id
                 );
```